# Datenwerke ReportServer, trouble adding custom Data Source (Caché)

Tags: sql, groovy, reportserver, intersystems-cache

I'm working with Datenwerke ReportServer.  I'm trying to consume a Caché source via DJBC.  [Here is a blog post from them on adding additional databases](http://blog.datenwerke.net/2013/06/adding-support-for-additional-databases.html).  Unfortunately, I don't fully understand it.  I have the JDBC file in the right place and I have created a groovy script for Caché which is below.  The problem is related to the weird Query Wrapper thing it does.  I can successfully test the datasource via the ReportServer UI, but when I try to execute a simple query, I get the following error:

> Error
>
> Query could not be prepared: Error preparing statement for
>   executing the report query : SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP
>   10 * FROM HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation) wrappedQry) limitQry
>   LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 /* token: 6aab148a-927b-45d5-9dfd-724788e139ca */ /*
>   currentuser: 3 */

**cache.groovy**

```
package databasehelper;

import net.datenwerke.rs.scripting.service.scripting.scriptservices.GlobalsWrapper;
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.dbhelper.DatabaseHelper
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.dbhelper.hooks.DatabaseHelperProviderHook
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.dbhelper.queries.Query
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.dbhelper.querybuilder.ColumnNamingService
import net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.dbhelper.querybuilder.QueryBuilder

class Cache extends DatabaseHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Cache";
    public static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver";
    public static final String DB_DESCRIPTOR = "DBHelper_Cache";

    @Override
    public String getDescriptor() {
        return DB_DESCRIPTOR;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDriver() {
        return DB_DRIVER;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String createDummyQuery() {
    return 'SELECT * FROM HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation'
    }

}


def HOOK_NAME = "DATASOURCE_HELPER_Cache"

def callback =  [
            provideDatabaseHelpers : {
                return Collections.singletonList(new Cache());
            }
        ] as DatabaseHelperProviderHook;

GLOBALS.services.callbackRegistry.attachHook(HOOK_NAME, DatabaseHelperProviderHook.class, callback)
```

Seems like a longshot posting this here, especially with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice generated query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation) 
wrappedQry) limitQry LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Caché SQL does not support `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

`%VID` and `TOP` can be used in Caché SQL instead of `LIMIT` / `OFFSET`:
http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_views#GSQL_C13474

Comment: Sadly I have moved on, but I appreciate the post and will accept in hopes it helps someone in the future :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson Yes. That is the hope. I understand that two months after question was asked, you probably does not need the answer :-)